# Excel date to int

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I am reading excel using pandas. In excel I am having date in dd-Mon-yy format while reading excel into list it is showing following

2019-10-31 00:00:00 and it is showing

```
<class 'pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp'>
```

I want to convert this into int in YYYYMMDD format, e.g.
20191031

How can I do this in most efficient way ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Series.dt.strftime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html) with casting to integers by [`Series.astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.astype.html):

```
rng = pd.date_range('2019-10-31', periods=3)
df = pd.DataFrame({'date': rng})
print (df)
        date
0 2019-10-31
1 2019-11-01
2 2019-11-02

df['int'] = df['date'].dt.strftime('%Y%m%d').astype(int)
print (df)
        date       int
0 2019-10-31  20191031
1 2019-11-01  20191101
2 2019-11-02  20191102

print (df.dtypes)
date    datetime64[ns]
int              int32
dtype: object
```